# I need to be able to mention ancient authors with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing

[image]

The first time, a citation should look like this:

> Livio, ab urbe condita 1,7

that means "Livio, book 1, paragraph 7",

Another time, still book 1 (one) but citing another paragraph, it should look like this

> Livio op.cit. 1, 20, or ibíd 1,20

With package `[style=verbose-inote,singletitle=false]{biblatex}` and `biblatex-source-division` i can obtain the first citation, but cannot get the output of the second cites.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Please see the cites 1,4 and 5 for the differences.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Whar you want is not very clear to me. Could you post a minimal working example?

Comment: I prefer to create my own citation commands for pre-modern works, but there is this biblatex package, which is designed for this purpose (written by a student of, I believe, late antiquity). See [here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-source-division).

Comment: I use customised bibliography strings and pagination settings when I need to cite things with a specialist, non-default format. Things like the use of Latin abbreviations are a matter of choosing appropriate bibliography and citation styles.

Comment: @cfr This is not really helpful. How does one cite Polybios or Livius today with biblatex?

Comment: @KeksDose It was intended to supplement jon's suggestions. I was just saying what I tend to do in these sorts of cases. You can set pagination options on a per entry basis. You can enable the Latin abbreviations of your choice, together with appropriate tracking. I don't see why mentioning this is not helpful. Of course, it doesn't give code. But neither does the question. And I'm not clear enough about the question to create code either. What is the first `1` in `1Livio...`? Where does the `11` come from? What happened to `17`? Why`1, 11` but `1,7`? Why no comma and lowercase in `polybio`?

Comment: Try one of the `verbose-trad` styles e.g. `verbose-trad1`, `verbose-trad2` or `verbose-trad3`.

Comment: Almost, but it  no  perfect for me, now in the second citation is, Livio op.cit,  but I continue without see  the book and the paragraph mention :(, i suppose that is possible used someone \DeclareName or other possibility.

Comment: Could you maybe add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) preferably one with a bibliography entry ([MWEB](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)) showing your latest solution, so we have something to play around with?

Comment: That said, when I last had to cite "classical" works (OK, it was Hobbes' *De Cive*, hardly classical, but still organised in the part-book-chapter way and almost exclusively cited so), I just created a little command that dealt with the proper "pagination" and the rest went pretty smoothly.

Comment: There's `biblatex-dw` and some similar packages, see http://biblatex.dominik-wassenhoven.de for a good overview (most of it is in German, though...). Several packages are summarised there; at some point it's imho almost easier to create an own style, though; the package documentations are a great help there!

Comment: Could you please make your question more specific? The comments you have received are about the best we can do lacking further information. A MWE showing what you have so for would be really welcome.